# How to set up custom controls - Pan using Mouse 4 + MMB

Tags: customization

I would like to change my user preferences to pan the 3D view using Mouse 4 button + Middle Mouse Button and dragging it. This is the same as SHIFT+MMB. I would like to use Mouse 4 instead of shift.

I am using a Logitech G5 mouse which has 2 extra buttons on the side and I would like to use them. The buttons are recognised in Blender, that's not the problem. In Blender it is referred to as Button 4.

In User Preferences under the Input tab under 3D View I have created a new shortcut. I have tried multiple possibilities but none seem to work.
I tried copying the same as the shift+mmb entry and replacing shift with Button 4 but that doesn't seem to work. I have tried using view3D.view_pan (as in the shortcut using ctrl+mouse wheel) but that also doesn't seem to work. I have tried the press and click and numerous other options, also changing Middle to Move instead. none seem to work.

I have saved my settings as default and am using a custom preset.

Am I missing something?

**edit:** I am using a new custom preset. Besides this new entry, everything else is set to default.

*updated picture: expanded view3d move modal*
[image: custom shortcut]

*Settings for default shortcut SHIFT+MMB*
[image: default shortcut]

note that the shortcut says "Button4 **Mouse Middle**" as opposed to "Middle Mouse". I don't know why. This might have something to do with it.
Or as mentioned in the comments, maybe Blender does not support mouse buttons as modifiers.

Comment: Below the expanded entry, there's *View3D Move Modal*, which belongs to the above entry. Make sure it's the same as for the default *Move view* keybinding (and adapt for Button4).

Comment: Interesting.. I tried this on linux, however blender does not seem to allow mouse buttons as custom modifiers.

Comment: It doesn't accept any mouse button as `key_modifier` here, how strange. Even tried to re-bind it via PyConsole: `>>> C.window_manager.keyconfigs['Blender User'].keymaps['3D View'].keymap_items[3].key_modifier = 'BUTTON4MOUSE' # -> 'NONE'`

Comment: Count me in on that question. Does mouse button 4 have some priveleges the other buttons haven't? Miva2, how did you make blender accept the button?

Comment: Just to be clear, `button 4` did work as the main button (not as a modifier)

Comment: @CoDEmanX, I haven't touched it. It looked fine. Screenshot above.

<br>@gandalf3, That would be really strange and illogical. The button is placed perfectly for use as a modifier and there is a separate box for custom modifiers. 

<br>@Haunt_House, What do you mean exactly with privileges? The button isn't used anywhere else. This is the only custom shortcut. I just pressed the button and it works.

I have noticed that in my custom shortcut it says "Button4 Mouse Middle" while the default says "Shift Middle Mouse"

Comment: I mean, you have *Button4* written in the field next to *Alt* and *Cmd* while I cannot do that with any mouse button. I click it, the field says 'press a key' and I do and it stays blank unless it's a keyboard key.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to use *MB4 + MMB* instead of just using *MB4* to pan? If you have five buttons I would think that would be sufficient...

Comment: Haunt_House, I clicked that field and pressed my mouse button. It worked.

@WChargin, That is also a possibility. I just prefer to use it as modifier instead of pinning a single action to it. I believe i tried that and didn't work. Might have filled in the fields wrong that time.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't use a mouse button as a `key modifier`, but only keyboard keys. (I don't know how you have set up "Button4" in the input)

"Button4" is only available in the drop-down list of mouse buttons :

[image]

Comment: This makes `button 4` move the view, OP said they wanted only a combination of `button 4` and `MMB` to move the view. ("I would like to change my user preferences to pan the 3D view using Mouse 4 button + Middle Mouse Button and dragging it")

Comment: Very strange. It just worked for me.
Yes, I wanted to use Button4 as modifier. I believe I have tried this and it didn't work (but that might be because I did something wrong)
Will look into it more.